# Trying to resolve CSS :nth-child formula with elements with a gallery

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to get a gallery with a repeated pattern. The gallery consists of 2 columns and undefined rows, and I want one picture to have 60% width and the other one 40%.

But on the second row should invert that order and never be like the row before.

So would end a repeated pattern like this:

[image]

The problem starts when I have a lot of pictures and I can't get to write that pattern with help of `nth-child`.

This is what I got closets to:

```css
p:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

p:nth-child(2n-2) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

p:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

p:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
```

How can I get the formula? Which one would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `4n+x` (where x is a value between 1 and 4) as `nth-child` values as shown below

```css
p:nth-child(4n+1),
p:nth-child(4n+4) {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

p:nth-child(4n+2),
p:nth-child(4n+3) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
<p>The 10th paragraph.</p>
<p>The 11th paragraph.</p>
<p>The 12th paragraph.</p>
<p>The 13th paragraph.</p>
```